# Android Push Notification - Title appears blank

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, push

I am using `phone-gap` for both android and ios app.

I have recently build `push notifications` for the APP however there is a problem with the android notification outside of the app itself.

The notification comes in fine and the message displays fine however the app name is blank?

Does anyone know why this may be? The app is live in the play store.

Comment: Post some code to get best solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Push Notifications: How do I show a title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666298/android-push-notifications-how-do-i-show-a-title)

Comment: You must add a "title" property to your payload.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/21666298/276648