# Android Push Notifications: How do I show a title?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

We are using the [Google Cloud Messaging API](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#params) to push Android notifications. We are executing the https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send endpoint with a payload similar to:

```
{
  "registration_ids" : ["..."],
  "data" : {
    "message" : "You received cash back!"
  }
}
```

The notification works and the phone shows our app logo, and the message from above. However, there is no title in the notification (above the message and to the right of the logo):

[image: Example Screenshot]

For reference, we are using Phonegap 3.3 and PhoneGap Build.

Answer (score 10):

Well, a stab in the dark of adding "title" fixed it. I wasn't able to find this documented at http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#params

```
{
  "registration_ids" : ["..."],
  "data" : {
    "message" : "You received cash back!",
    "title" : "Title"
  }
}
```

Now in docs:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#payload

Comment: The `title` is not documented in the GCM docs, since it's not part of the GCM API. It's a custom property, and its handling depends on the code you are running in your client app for displaying the notification.

Comment: Ahh, I see, so the message and title are probably handled by the Phonegap plugin. Thanks.

Comment: Check the `createNotification` method of https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/android/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java You'll see it expects some fields like `message` & `title`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref):

```
{
  "registration_ids" : ["..."],
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "You received cash back!",
    "title" : "Title",
    "icon": "ic_notification" // replace with your own
  }
}
```

Edit: cloud messaging is now deprecated and this example is no longer valid. The link to the updated documentation is at [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server)

Answer (score 0):

its working my side

$message = array("message" => $pushMessage,"title" => "My Notification");
$fields = array(
    "registration_ids" => "`device id to send notification`",
            "data" => $message
     );